# WPF ComboBox: Bind SelectedItem to a Class-Member

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, binding

I have a class Person with an Id (Int32) and Name (String). The names of the Persons Collection are shown in a ComboBox (DisplayMemberPath="Name"). I want bind the selected item's Id to a property Int32 SelectedId in the viewmodel.

I have tried SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedId, Mode=TwoWay}"
and SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=SelectedId, Mode=TwoWay}", both do not work.

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbPersons"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm},Path=Persons}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedValue="Id"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedId, Mode=TwoWay}"
/>
```

Comment: I saw that I made an error when I wrote the example. Id is Int32. But it did'nt work anyway.

Comment: Excuse me, but I think it makes sense to follow @
Mathivanan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
SelectedValuePath="Id"
```

**Update:**

I prepared a sample which is working fine. I hope it will clarify you. (Implement INotifyPropertyChanged by yourself)

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Raj" },
            new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Ram" }
        };
    }
}
```

**Person.cs:**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
   <ComboBox Width="100" Height="30" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId}" SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
```

Comment: Note that neither setting `Mode=TwoWay` nor `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is necessary here, because both are already the default for the SelectedValue property.

Comment: I just saw that in my example above I made an error: SelectedValue="Id" should be SelectedValuePath="Id" as in Your example. But it does not work anyway.

Comment: Whats is your Persons collection?

Comment: The Persons collection is an ObservableCollection. The SelectedId Setter is not called when I change the the item of the ComboBox. It works, if I change the data typ of SelectedId from Int32 to the class Person and use SelectedItem intead of SelectedValuePath and Selected Value.

Comment: Did you implement the onproperty changed on all the concerned properties ?

Comment: Yes, I just verified it. The Setter of SelectedId will not be called when selected item changes.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your example. I got it running by inserting the DataContext explicitely to the ComboBox. Before I had the DataContect in the overlying Grid (I thought all childs will have the same DataContext). But I still wonder, why it worked with "SelectedItem" (see 2 comments above).

Comment: Yes, parent's DataContext will be derived to all the child controls unless you change the DataContext explicitly.

Comment: Thank You all very much for Your help. One question: Do You know a tool to analyze Bindings?

Answer (score 0):

In case it's primarly about getting the selected item and not about the binding.

You can get the selected item without binding it to an extra property. You can use `ICollectionView` to get an event in the viewmodel when another item gets selected.

Code for the viewmodel

```
List<PersonVm> personVms;
private ICollectionView _persons;

public ICollectionView Persons
{
    get => _persons;
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _persons)) return;
        _persons = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

// call this method in the constructor of the viewmodel
private void Init(){
    // TODO You have to add items to personVms before creating the collection

    Persons = new CollectionView(personVms);

    // Event when another item gets selected
    Persons.CurrentChanged += PersonsOnCurrentChanged;

    // moves selected index to postion 2
    Persons.MoveCurrentToPosition(2); 
}

private void PersonsOnCurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // the currently selected item
    PersonVm personVm = (PersonVm)Persons.CurrentItem;

    // the currently selected index
    int personsCurrentPosition = Persons.CurrentPosition;
}
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```